# inheritance of class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have output for this program that I don't understand how does it happens
here is the output

i from A is 40

i from A is 60

i from B is 60

I do understand the first line of output but nothing after that. Does this have to do with polymorphism ?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
        new B();
    }
}

class A {

    int i = 7;

    public A() {

        setI(20);

        System.out.println("i from A is " + i);

    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = 2 * i;

    }
}

class B extends A {

    public B() {

        System.out.println("i from B is " + i);
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = 3 * i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Constructor of subclass calls constructor of superclass.

Comment: @ sje397 OK I know that but still that won't lead me to get that output.

Comment: You also have overridden `setI()`, so when `B` runs the code in `A`s constructor, `B#setI()` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. B extends A meaning it is a subclass of A.
Thus it shares i which is initialized only in A and then shared in B.
So B starts with what?
An i with "initial" value equal to 20.

Answer (score 1):

It is java functionality
Whenever you create a child class object default constructor/argument-less constructor implicitly gets called.

And in your case first call is to A() constructor and then B() constuctor, and method  call get to local method of B class

`ie   public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = 3 * i;
    }

If you want to avoid this you can do this by making a call to super class constructor explicitly.

For example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // new A();
        new B();
    }
}

class A {

    int i = 7;

    public A() {

        setI(20);

        System.out.println("i from A is " + i);

    }

    public A(int x)
    {
          System.out.println("This is  a super call");
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = 2 * i;

    }
}

class B extends A {

    public B() {

        super(10);
        System.out.println("i from B is " + i);
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = 3 * i;
    }

}
```

Output will be :

This is  a super call
i from B is 7